# Using React-Router to navigate between components on the same page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on the todo list, where we have one main page with a list of items, and all manipulations with them (creation, editing, viewing) happens through the modal windows, and now I need to add some "routing" for these modal windows (e.g. user inserts some specific URL into browser's address bar and the app should be displayed with opened modal window)

I'm considering adding a hash to the URL, e.g. for the creation it should be "#create-task" and then handle the hash change in the custom useEffect like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.hash === 'create-task') {
      openCreateTaskModal();
    } else if (location.hash === 'view-task') {
      openViewTaskModal(id); // "id" also should be parsed from URL
    }
  }, [location.hash])
```

What do you think about this solution, maybe there are better ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, best practice.

```js
import { Route } from "react-router";

...

return (
  <div>
    <Route path="/create">
      <CreateComponent />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/view/:id">
      <ViewComponent />
    </Route>
   
  </div>
);
```